# htaccess rewrite every URL.org/(persian phrase)

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I tried this but didn't work:

```
RewriteRule    ^/([\u0600-\u06FF]+)/?$    /tag.php?value=$1     [NC,L]
```

It'll be acceptable for me to rewrite every phrase except phrases that includes English characters (and maybe) plus some numbers, spaces and this characters _ , ! and -  .

As an Example I want rewrite this:

```
URL.org/مطلب 2 درمورد وب
```

to

```
/tag.php?value=مطلب 2 درمورد وب
```

But if URL is something like

```
URL.org/Basic 4 Android_2
```

I just want to index the folder "Basic 4 Android_2" and not do any rewrite..

EDIT :
Let me make it easier,
I just want to not rewrite any URL in this format

```
URL.com/Completely_English_Phrase_Without_Any_NonEnglish_Chars(persian_japonese_chenese,russian and ....)
```

But I want to Rewrite any URL in the following format

```
 URL.com/AnyPhrase_That_Includes_1_OR_More_nonEnglishChars_Like_ب_语_ษ_й_and_so_on
```

to tag.php

Comment: You could prepend a RewriteCond that takes the URI and checks for the absence of latin characters and only then the RewriteRule is interpreted: `RewriteCond %REQUEST_URI ^[^a-z]*$ [NC]`

Comment: tank u , but that's not what I'm looking for, In the case you mentioned it'll rewrite URL.com/B4A_Tutorial to tag.php that I don't want to..

Comment: Did you test that, or did you assume that?

Comment: I assumed :) . this is the line I'm using now : RewriteRule    ^((?:[^/]*)[^\x01-\x7F](?:[^/]*))/?$ tag.php?value=$1 [QSA,B,L]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?(.*[^\x01-\x7F].*?)/?$ tag.php?value=$1 [QSA,B,L]
```

- `[^\x01-\x7F]` will match any character that is not in ASCII range i.e. `1-127`

Comment: Thank you, It works in some cases , but not for the example I mentioned before URL.org/مطلب 2 درمورد وب ...

Comment: BTW , what's "?:"  for?

Comment: `(?:..)` is non-capturing group in regex. Also on my Apache, it worked for me on your example URL `URL.org/مطلب 2 درمورد وب`  Unfortunately I cannot understand persian so can only try given examples by copy/pasting.

Comment: Thanks, you don't need to understand Persian , It'll be good enough for me to just rewrite anything that includes some non English chars to tag.php..

Comment: I've added you code to htaccess ,Please visit this URL https://www.zanjan.org/%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85_%D9%85%D9%86

Comment: Thank You, what about this , It doesn't works for https://www.zanjan.org/%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%87_%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%87_SomeEnglish

Comment: I gave you a Hindi URL coz I guess U R hindi :)

Comment: That is because `SomeEnglish` is ASCII character not part of our regex. (Let me update one more time). Yes you guessed it right that I understand Hindi :)